# How to make substitution without getting Recursion Limit Error

Tags: replacement

So I just have a complicated expression on the form
 `z = DiagonalMatrix[{-w'[t]^3 L''[t] (1 + w'[t]^2) - L'[t]^3 H (e^(2 H w[t]) - w'[t]) + (1 - e^(-2 H w[t])) H w'[t]^3 L'[t] + L''[t] w'[t]^2 (w''[t] + H) (1' L'[t]^2), -e^(-2 H w[t]) H L[t]^2 L'[t] - w'[t] L, -H  e^(2 H w[t]) L[t]^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 L'[t] - L[t] Sin[\[Theta]]^2 w'[t]}]`

However, now I basically want to eliminate w'[t]. I have known expressions for them so I just want to substitute
$$ w'[t] = e^{H w[t]} (1+L'[t]^2)$$

How do I do this without copy pasting the expressions? If I just define w'[t] I get error. If I write something like
`Simplify[z, Assumptions -> {w'[t] == (1 + L'[t]^2) e^(2 H x[t])}]` I also get the same
error. ```

What should I do? Also, should I substitute w'|t] and w'[t]^2 respectively or will Mathematica understand to also substitute any power of w[t]?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use  `z /. w'[t] -> (1 + L'[t]^2) e^(2 H x[t])`? does this not work?  if you had `w` and want to replaces it and all its derivatives, then use `Function[{t},...]` instead. But you just want to change w' here.

Comment: Is `e` meant to be a variable or the constant `E`?

Comment: So I don't have anything else in my notebook. My first line defines z. So there is no interference you are not aware of. This is what I get: 
"$RecursionLimit::reclim2"

Comment: The constant e, Eulers number.

Comment: Then use capital `E`

Comment: For some reason, I now get the same error just defining z.. Hmm. Even if I copy past it into a new notebook, what heppened? Do Mathematica recognize the history of clippboard code?

Comment: @JohanHansen if you open a second notebook with `ctrl + n`, the variables defined in one will be in the other. Just run Quit[] to quit kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of mistakes in your definition of z. If e is to be the Euler constant, then it should be capitalized. Also, near the end of `z[[1,1]]` you have `(1' L'[t]^2)`. Bearing that in mind, this should do the job:

```
z /. {w' -> f,w'' :> ( f'[#] &)} /. {f :> ((1 + L'[#]^2) E^(2 H x[#]) &)}
```

The first substitution labels w' as a different function f, and then in the second substitution you substitute in the definition of f using a pure function so that derivatives are correctly calculated.